# Configuration properties cannot be loaded in a multiple-module project

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build up a multiple-module project, every module would be loaded by executing the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigure` properties, then I found the properties were not injected when I started to run. Instead, it's still using the default property, for example, I configure the input expression in the main class as `Value("${esb.mas.path:/home/mas}")`
, and define `esb.mas.path=/home/vfs/mas` in the corresponding module property file, but the modified values were never used.

By debugging and tracing the code, I found the problem, but I am still not sure if this is a bug from spring framework, in the following lines,

```
public String org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(String value) {
        String result = value;
        for (StringValueResolver resolver : this.embeddedValueResolvers) {
            if (result == null) {
                return null;
            }
            result = resolver.resolveStringValue(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I noticed that if the value of first place of `embeddedValueResolvers` list cannot be caught, they would use the default /home/mas, when continually resolving the `embeddedValueResolvers`, the parameter for method of `resolveStringValue` is the returned default value which is /home/mas, the real value of `esb.mas.path` was not used.

```
org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(String, PlaceholderResolver, Set<String>)
```